# KVM-QEMU bridged network not working - guest can only access host

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virsh, virt-manager

I am trying to configure VMs to act like devices on my LAN, instead of hiding behind the host.

This is the tutorial I followed: [RHEL8 Network Bridged Interface](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_RHEL_KVM_Networked_Bridge_Interface)

My router/DHCP is at 10.10.1.254

Host is a CentOS 8 VM running inside ESXi - on DHCP with IP 10.10.1.54 , host can access internet/LAN and VMs.

Guest is also CentOS 8 - manages to get DHCP lease with IP 10.10.1.55 but can't connect to anything other than the host. It can't even ping the router at 10.10.1.254 even though it somehow gets a DHCP lease. I tried enabling net.ipv4.ip_forward on the host but that didn't fix it.

I also tried netinstall of CentOS7 guest. It manages to pull settings via DHCP, but it doesn't have network access as well.

Here is the host config:

- ifcfg-bridge-slave-ens192

  ```
  TYPE=Ethernet
  NAME=bridge-slave-ens192
  UUID=...
  DEVICE=ens192
  ONBOOT=yes
  BRIDGE=br0
  ```
- ifcfg-br0

  ```
  STP=yes
  BRIDGING_OPTS=priority=32768
  TYPE=Bridge
  PROXY_METHOD=none
  BROWSER_ONLY=no
  BOOTPROTO=dhcp
  DEFROUTE=yes
  IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
  IPV6INIT=yes
  IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
  IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
  IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
  IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
  NAME=br0
  UUID=....
  DEVICE=br0
  ONBOOT=yes
  ```

Finally in virt-manager under VM NIC I have set "Specify shared device name" as network source, and then under bridge name I have "br0" and type is "virtio".

`# nmcli c show --active`

```
    Name                 -  Type    -  Device
    br0                  -  bridge  -  br0
    bridge-slave-ens192  -  ehernet -  ens192
    vnet0                -  tun     -  vnet0
```

`# virsh net-list -all`

```
    Name  -  State  -  Autostart  -  Persistent
    br0   -  active -  yes        -  yes
```

`# iptables -L`

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source      destination

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source      destination

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source      destination
```

`# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`

```
    net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in the bridged network configuration.

Since the KVM host is running inside ESXi as a VM I had to enable promiscuous mode on the ESXi vSwitch.

Enabling promiscuous mode in vSwitch security settings fixed my issue.